# How to update value of a Model's attribute in a for loop

Tags: ruby, model, update-attributes

I have the following code which works finde

```
twt = Tweet.where(user_id: @user.uid).where(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).first
            twt.status_id = 1
            twt.save
```

I the want to make this code run for every user available in the database:

```
@user = User.all
            @user.each do |u|
            twt = Tweet.where(user_id: u.uid).where(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).first
            twt.status_id = 1
            twt.save
            end
```

this however gives me the error:

```
undefined method `status_id=' for nil:NilClass
```

why is there no class found? Why wasn't it set correctly in twt?

Comment: If you have many users you should do it in batches. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, for some user, this line

```
twt = Tweet.where(user_id: u.uid).where(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).first
```

found no results. You could add

```
if twt
  twt.status_id = 1
  twt.save
end
```

Anyway, you can rewrite that as

```
Tweet.find_by(user_id: u.uid, status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id)
```

Obviously, it's possible to do all this job in just one SQL query.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Comment: Or u.tweets.find_by(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).  And you probably can get away w/o adding order (ex. u.tweets.find_by(status_id: 0))  as the auto inserted created_at is going always to be in the same order as id unless there are other updates or imported records.

Comment: @s1mpl3 yes you are right, dont really need the order in there but just me beeing extra careful ;)